# there is noly three checkbox in jupyter notebook nbextentions

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-contrib-nbextensions

I am insatlling jupyter notebook nbextensions on my window serer which can not connect to Internet,the version of NBextensions is 0.5.1 .

However ,I got only three checkbox on the tab of NBextensions, and I can't find Hintreland checkbox, what should I do now?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3jhP.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
```

I have got the anser